# How to duplicate too many records with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, duplicates

I need to read and process (for example add a "2" at the end of IDs + some other things...) and re-insert at least 2000 records form MySQL with PHP.
It's not possible to do it with a SQL Query...
The problem is when we click on the Go button, it processes almost 500 records but then we see a "Server Internal 500" error! but in localhost we don't have any problem...

Is there a way to do this with these limited resources in our customer websites?

Another question: What causes this problem? What resource needs to be more? RAM? CPU?...?

Here is the code:
(We should read all courses of a semester and all course selections and copy them to the new semester)

```
foreach ($courseList as $courseInfo)
    {
        $ccode=$courseInfo['ccode'];
        $lid=$courseInfo['lid'];
        $pid=$courseInfo['pid'];
        $clid=$courseInfo['clid'];
        $cgender=$courseInfo['cgender'];
        $descriptive_score=$courseInfo['descriptive_score'];
        $final_capacity=$courseInfo['final_capacity'];
        $days_times=$courseInfo['days_times'];
        $exam_date=$courseInfo['exam_date'];
        $exam_place=$courseInfo['exam_place'];
        $ccourse_start_date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $ccomment=$courseInfo['ccomment'];
        $cid=$courseInfo['cid'];
        $majors=$course->GetCourseMajorsList($cid);
        $scList=$course->GetCourseScoreColumnsList($cid);
        $courseScoreColums=array();
        foreach ($scList as $scProp)
        {
            $courseScoreColums[$scProp['scid']]=$scProp['scid'].','.$scProp['cscfactor'];
        }
        $tid = $term->LastTermID();
        $counts = $course->AddCourse($ccode.'2',$tid,$lid,$pid,$clid,$majors,$courseScoreColums,$cgender,$descriptive_score,$final_capacity,$days_times,NULL,$exam_place,$ccourse_start_date,$ccomment,$aid);
        if ($counts==1)
        {
            $new_cid = $course->LastCourseID();
            $cs = new ManageCourseStudents();
            $query = " WHERE `".$table_prefix."courses`.`cid`=$cid ";
            $courseStudentList = $cs->GetCourseStudentList($query,'');
            foreach ($courseStudentList as $csInfo)
                $cs->AddCourseStudent($csInfo['uid'],$new_cid,$csInfo['lvid'],$aid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: adding "2" at the end of an ID seems like something that SQL could do without the need for PHP

Comment: `update yourtable set idfield=concat(idfield,'2')`?

Comment: @Marc he mentioned he wants to concat other things also.

Comment: Something in your code causes the problem.... but unless you share your code, we can't tell you what

Comment: can you do a memory set by this statement ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M'); Just check it but its really not possible unless I see the code to tell exactly where the problem is.

Comment: Just check the error.log on your server and tell us what is the error. This way we can help you much more.

Comment: I added the code... please have a look and help me...

Answer (score 0):

```
$str    =   "select * from  tableName";  //replacing * by table columns is a good practice

$result =    $conn->query($str);

while($arr = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);)
{
   $strr1  = "  INSERT INTO  tableName (  `id` , `title` , `des` ) //add more
            VALUES (  '".$arr['id']."2',  '".$arr['something']."'   //add as you require
          ";

   if($conn->query($strr1) === false) {
      trigger_error('Wrong SQL: ' . $sql . ' Error: ' . $conn->error, E_USER_ERROR);
     } 
 }
```

this could duplicate every data in your database

Comment: Using deprecated MySQL extension, suppressing potential error messages with `@`, not really an answer to inspire confidence